# How to run a def with multiple values only once and use values into another def?

Tags: python, return

My problem is real simple but unfortunately i can't find a way to solve it.

I would like to run a def A which returns multiple values from def B only once.

I wrote this block of code :

```
def A():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return a,b,c

def B():
    d = A[0] + A[1]
    e = A[2] - A[0]
    print d,e

B()
```

If i'm using this block of code it will run four times!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just call A in your B function. `x,y,z = A()`

Comment: I assume the real `A` function is more complicated than returning a constant `tuple`? Otherwise, you may as well just avoid the function and define `A = 1, 2, 3` at the top level of the module, then you can index without calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, there are mistakes in your code, `A` is a function and you should call it with `A()` to get the returned values. Instead you use it like `A[0]` which is un-subscriptable, and you can assign a temp variable within `B` function so you can re-use the returned values, change to below should work:

```
In [54]: def A():
    ...:     x = 1
    ...:     y = 2
    ...:     z = 3
    ...:     return x,y,z  # I fixed your typo too
    ...:
    ...: def B():
    ...:     a = A()
    ...:     d = a[0] + a[1]
    ...:     e = a[2] - a[0]
    ...:     print(d,e)
    ...:
    ...: B()

    3 2
```

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos -- not a problem, yeah I think it's just an overseen mistake you've made and glad it's solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
def B():
    a, b, c = A()
    d = a + b
    e = c - a
    print d,e
```

But make sure your function `A()` is returning the same variables it is declaring (`x, y, z` not `a, b, c`).